# ggplot2 Facet Wrap Reorder by y-axis, Not x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot faceted bar graphs and order them left-to-right from the largest to smallest values. I should be able to do this with code similar to this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(reorder(cyl, -hwy), hwy)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = "free")
```

Instead what I get is ordering by the x-axis which happens to be 'cyl', smallest to largest values. How do I order descending, by the y-axis, so it looks like a Pareto chart? It has to be faceted as well. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to plot on the y-axis? Do you want the mean value of `hwy` for each level of `cyl`?

Comment: I get an error. What don't you reorder the factor in the data before the call to ggplot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a different approach that can be performed directly in ggplot utilizing two functions from [here](https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R). I will use eipi10's example:

```
library(tidyverse)
mpg$hwy[mpg$manufacturer=="audi" & mpg$cyl==8] <- 40

dat <- mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, cyl) %>% 
  summarise(hwy = mean(hwy)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(hwy)) %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = cyl))
```

Functions:

```
reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}


scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}
```

plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(reorder_within(cyl, -hwy, manufacturer), y = hwy), hwy) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

for ascending order you would: `reorder_within(cyl, hwy, manufacturer)`

Plot without the functions:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(cyl, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, the goal is to plot the average highway mpg (the `hwy` column) by `cyl` for each `manufacturer`. Within each `manufacturer`, you want to order the x-axis (the `cyl` values), by the mean `hwy` value for each `cyl`.

To do that, we need to create the plots separately for each manufacturer and then lay them out together. This is because we can't have different x-axis orderings (`cyl` orderings in this case) for different panels in the same plot. (UPDATE: I stand corrected. @missuse's answer links to [functions written by David Robinson](https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R), based on a [blog post by Tyler Rinker](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2016/12/23/ordering-categories-within-ggplot2-facets/) to vary the x-axis label order in facetted plots.) So, we'll create a list of plots and then lay them out together, as if they were facetted.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(egg)
```

Since in the real data, the mean value of `hwy` is always monotonically decreasing with increasing `cyl`, we'll create an artificially high `hwy` value for 8-cylinder Audis, just for illustration:

```
mpg$hwy[mpg$manufacturer=="audi" & mpg$cyl==8] = 40
```

Now we split the data by `manufacturer` so we can create a separate plot, and therefore a separate `cyl` ordering for each manufacturer. We'll use the `map` function to iterate over the manufacturers.

```
plot.list = split(mpg, mpg$manufacturer) %>% 
  map(function(dat) { 

    # Order cyl by mean(hwy)
    dat = dat %>% group_by(manufacturer, cyl) %>% 
      summarise(hwy = mean(hwy)) %>% 
      arrange(desc(hwy)) %>% 
      mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels=cyl))

    ggplot(dat, aes(cyl, hwy)) +
      geom_col() +
      facet_wrap(~ manufacturer) +
      theme(axis.title=element_blank()) +
      expand_limits(y=mpg %>% 
                      group_by(manufacturer,cyl) %>% 
                      mutate(hwy=mean(hwy)) %>% 
                      pull(hwy) %>% max)
  })
```

Now let's remove the y-axis values and ticks from the plot that won't be in the first column when we lay out the plots together:

```
num_cols = 5

plot.list[-seq(1,length(plot.list), num_cols)] =
  lapply(plot.list[-seq(1,length(plot.list), num_cols)], function(p) {
    p + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
              axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
  })
```

Finally, we lay out the plots. `ggarrange` from the `egg` package ensures that the panels all have the same width (otherwise the panels in the first column would be narrower than the others, due to space taken up by the y-axis labels).

```
ggarrange(plots=plot.list, left="Highway MPG", bottom="Cylinders", ncol=num_cols)
```

Note that the `cyl` values for `audi` are not in increasing order, showing that our reordering worked properly.

[image]

Comment: `facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = 'free_y')` doesn't free the scales on your plot above. How would I free the y scale?

Comment: Just remove the `expand_limits` statement to get the equivalent of free scales. However, I like @missuse's answer better.