# ggplot - ordering bars in geom_bar facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

with a dataframe like below

```
set.seed(99)
data = data.frame(name=c("toyota", "nissan"), a=sample(1:10,2)/10,b=sample(-150:-50,2),c=sample(1e2:1e3,2),d=sample(1e3:1e5,2), e=sample(-15:30,2))
```

I'm trying to plot the various variables onto a single chart as below. This works well

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(data, id = "name")) + 
  aes(name, value, fill = name) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank()
    )
```

[image]

The issue I have is that I want the bars in each facet to be ordered with highest values first - how do I go about this ? Note that I still need to keep the order in legend as it is - that is `nissan`, `toyota`

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203269/496488) do what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with the following idea after reading Mr. Flick's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179726/ordering-factors-in-each-facet-of-ggplot-by-y-axis-value/48180082#48180082). I would like to give him  credit.

What Mr. Flick did in the question is to create a new factor variable. Right now you have Nissan and Toyota. But we want to assign a unique factor level for each of Nissan and Toyota; we want to create ten levels. We want to find the proper order for each of the car company in each level of `variable`. The outcome of this process is stored as `foo`. In the next step, we want to create a new factor variable, which is identical to `foo` in `mutate()` in the previous code. Then, assign levels using `foo`. In the code for ggplot, we want to use `scales = "free"`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

temp <- melt(data, id = "name")

# Deciding the level order

foo <- temp %>%
       group_by(variable) %>%
       mutate(foo = levels(reorder(factor(paste(name, variable, sep = ".")), -value))) %>%
       pull(foo)

# Creating a new factor variable and assign levels with foo.

out <- temp %>% 
       mutate(new = factor(interaction(name, variable), levels = foo))

ggplot(data = out, aes(x = new, y = value, fill = name)) +
geom_col(position = "dodge") +
facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free") +
labs(x = "", fill = "Car company") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: tried this, I'm afraid it is not working as intended. In the graph above for variable `c` the bar corresponding to `toyota` should have come before `nissan`

Comment: @user3206440 Just apply `fct_rev(name)` within the `aes()` call.

Comment: @user3206440 Let me get back to you a bit later. I am at work now.

Comment: @user3206440 Thanks for waiting. I tried a few things and came up with the code above. This time, Nissan comes on left side for variable `b` and `c`. I think this is the right order.

Comment: @jazzurro - I tried this and it worked very well - thank you :). In case I want to show x-axis tick mark label text, how would I get rid of the `.variable` part from the label ?

Comment: @user3206440 you mean something like `.a` in the x-axis text? If that is the case, you perhaps want to use `gsub()` as Mr. Flick did in the question that I cited.

Comment: @user3206440 I had a chance to sit down and think about the x label issue. I initially thought `scale_x_discrete(breaks = new, labels = gsub(pattern = "(^.*)\\..*$", replacement = "\\1", x = new))` would do the job. But this is causing an error. I am still thinking what is causing this.

Comment: @user3206440 I just saw you posted a new question and I came back to this challenge again. The following code is working with the sample data here. Somehow we need to specify `out$new` rather than `new`. Give it a go. `ggplot(data = out, aes(x = new, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_col(position = "dodge") + facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free") +labs(x = "", fill = "Car company") + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +scale_x_discrete(breaks = out$new, labels = gsub(pattern = "(^.*)\\..*$", replacement = "\\1", x = out$new)) `