# How to sort bars after grouped top_n in facet_wrap with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-wrap, top-n

I'm facing an issue with sorting bars when using `facet_wrap` (which is commonly reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257093/ggplot-ordering-bars-in-geom-bar-facet-wrap), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph) and others) after group variables and get top values.
When I run the code without factor conversion, bars are ordered:

```
iris %>% 
  gather(key = measurements, value = values, - Species) %>% 
  mutate(kk = factor(measurements, levels = unique(.$measurements)),
         species_l = with(., paste(Species, .$measurements, sep = "_"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(species_l, values),
             y = values, 
             fill = kk)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(.~kk,
             scales = "free")
```

But now I want to order decreasingly bars within `facet_wrap` and after `top_n`.
Heres is what I've tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  gather(key = measurements, value = values, - Species) %>% 
  within(., 
         Species <- factor(Species, 
                          levels=names(sort(table(Species), 
                                            decreasing=FALSE)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species,
             y = values, 
             fill = measurements)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(.~ measurements,
             scales = "free")
```

and this:

```
iris %>% 
  gather(key = measurements, value = values, - Species) %>% 
  group_by(measurements, Species) %>% 
  top_n(5, wt = values) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Species, Species,
                         function(x)-length(x)),
             y = values, 
             fill = measurements)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(.~measurements,
             scales = "free")
```

and this:

```
iris %>% 
  gather(key = measurements, value = values, - Species) %>% 
  mutate(kk = factor(measurements, levels = unique(.$measurements)),
         species_l = with(., paste(Species, .$measurements, sep = "_"))) %>% 
  group_by(measurements, Species) %>%
  top_n(5, wt = values) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(species_l, values),
             y = values, 
             fill = kk)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(.~kk,
             scales = "free")
```

This is what I get:
[image]

As you can see `Sepal.Width` bars are not sorted.

Comment: Try these too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214071/how-to-order-data-by-value-within-ggplot-facets/52214383#52214383

Comment: @Tung can you read edits. I'm trying to reopen since with `top_n` and `group_modify` it seems that answers marked as duplicated from don't fit my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt was close -- you need to make sure you're reordering per facet, and not just reordering the factor based on the top 5 values of all measurements. Julia Silge explains thoroughly [here](https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/)

```
library(tidytext) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magtrittr)

iris %>%
   gather(key = measurements, value = values, - Species) %>% 
    mutate(kk = factor(measurements, levels = unique(.$measurements)),
#The '-values' below specifies to order in descending
      Species = reorder_within(Species, -values, measurements)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = values, fill = kk)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        facet_wrap(.~kk, scales = "free") +
      scale_x_reordered()`
```